# Diagnosing an HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 that does not charge

Tags: laptop, battery, usb-c, charging, hp-elitebook

I am attempting to diagnose why an HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 does not charge on its USB-C ports.

**Symptoms:**

**When the battery is connected**:

- No charging diode remains off, whichever the port to which the power chord is connected.

**When the battery is not connected**

- The charging diode blinks 8 times (in 8 white+orange sequences), then goes off if the power chord is inserted in the USB-C port that is the closest from the battery, but does not blink at all if inserted in the other port.

**Voltages measured**

- If the power chord is inserted in the USB-C port that is the closest from battery (see picture below), the voltage at each of the two the orange circled components (capacitor and likely a TVS fuse diode) is 19,7 V. No voltage (or insignificant) and the capacitor between the two ports, circled in red on the picture.
- If the power chord is inserted in the other USB-C port (closest from the HDMI socket), there is no voltage at both the capacitor between the USB-C ports, nor at the orange circled components.
- The voltage between the red and black cables of the battery is around 7,75V.

N.B. The battery is assumed deeply discharged.

Motherboard components are visually in good condition, as well as the USB-C sockets.

**I assume the problem could come from a shorted capacitor between the two USB-C sockets**, like in this video at minute 6: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oEXIbVD9Bo

This failure appears to me more likely than a damaged/defective USB-C socket, because the charging problem is with both ports, but I would appreciate if some of you could confirm the plausibility of this diagnosis.

[image: Partial view of the motherboard of an HP EliteBook x360 1030 G3 not charging.]